# Importing JS package into a required file

Tags: javascript, import, vuetify.js

I have two Javascript files.

bootstrap.js:

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
Vue.use(Vuetify);
```

app.js:

```
require('bootstrap');

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),  
    data: () => ({
    })
});
```

When I import `vuetify` in the `bootstrap.js` file, and then require `bootstrap.js` into `app.js` in receive an error:

> Vuetify is not defined

However when I move the `vuetify` import into the same `app.js` file, it resolves the error.

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
Vue.use(Vuetify);

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),  
    data: () => ({
    })
});
```

Why can't I import the package into a seperate file and then require the file with the imported package like I have done?

Comment: `Vuetify` is only *available* in the scope of that module

Comment: you're mixing `import` and `require` ... any reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export `Vuetify` from `bootstrap.js` like below

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
Vue.use(Vuetify);

export Vuetify;
```

and then `Vuetify` will be available in `app.js` file. You have to import `Vuetify` in `app.js`. Your app.js will look something like this

```
var Vuetify = require('bootstrap');

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),  
    data: () => ({
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE — module features are imported into the scope of a single script — they will not be available in the global scope. Therefore, you will only be able to access imported features in the script they are imported into, and you won't be able to access them like the way you are trying!

There is is a difference between classic scripts and module scripts. You can read in more detail in this [Web.dev](https://v8.dev/features/modules) article.